# Error: Could not find or load main class org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter,

Tags: automated-tests

I am getting this error while executing run configurations for testng.xml file and debugging the test cases in maven Project. I added almost all dependencies in pom.xml file. Any ideas regarding this error??

Comment: what errors? what is in your pom.xml?

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter,